# MySQL Trigger Sum Two Columns where userID is the same

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have the following product table

```
id | companyID | prodID | price | stock | stockAvailable | sumStock
1    A           2         10      5       4                    
2    B           2         50      10      5
```

I need to have a trigger when I update a product row that will update the sumStock.

I am new to Triggers, my attempt failed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `SalesDB`.`stockSumUpdate` BEFORE UPDATE
    ON SalesDB.Product FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET Product.sumStock = Product.stock + Product.stockAvailable
END
```

My Goal is in this case to calculate the SUM(stock) AS stockSum Where ProductID=2
in this case that would be 15 and then add that to the sumStock. Then add the stockAvailable column to that as well. So in sumStock for both collumns I would have 24.

Result would be:

```
id | companyID | prodID | price | stock | stockAvailable | sumStock
1    A           2         10      5       4               29     
2    B           2         50      10      5               29
```

Comment: And how did the attempt fail?

Comment: It does not calculate the sum where every productID is the Same. I have been unable to figure out how to do that. I need to calculate the sum of all products that have the same ProductID and then update them all with sumStock... this only does it by row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `SalesDB`.`stockSumUpdate` BEFORE UPDATE
    ON SalesDB.Product FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.sumStock = NEW.stock + NEW.stockAvailable
END;
```

That adds within a row of a table.

To get the total, you would use something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `SalesDB`.`stockSumUpdate` BEFORE UPDATE
    ON SalesDB.Product FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.sumStock = (select sum(stock + stockAvailable)
                        from products where p.prodid = new.prodid and p.id <> id
                       ) + NEW.stock + NEW.stockAvailable;
END;
```

Except, this still, doesn't do what you want.  If you are updating multiple rows at a time, you will get different total stock values.

In other words, you are trying to update a group of rows whenever you update a single row.  Gosh, when put like that, it doesn't seem like a good idea.   The second set of udpates could update even *more* rows and so on and so on (it wouldn't happen because of the product).

Instead, create a table with product as a primary key and the stock available in that table (might be an existing table).  Then update the summary table every time there is a change in this table.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I may have mislead you.

I need to sum all values in column stock that have the same ID and then add as well the stockAvailable that has the same ID and put that value in the sumStock. I have updated the question and thanks for the edits.

Comment: I will try that code. Rows will be updated one at a time in a syncronization process. The issue is that I have multiple companies that have the same productIDs and I need to have a stock that is the sum of all stocks available in all companies. The stock is updated from SQLserver to a MySQL database

Comment: @AdamSurfari . . . I still think you should put the available stock in a separate table and `join` it in as needed for other purposes.  With a primary key on `prodid`, the join should be pretty fast.  And, you can use a view to hide it.

Comment: I agree that would be a better way, but the way the datamodel is right now there isn't an easy way to create a new table, it was already a struggle to approve the creation of this field (the alternative would be a client side query that needed all the data from all companies). Ill have to try and do it this way, if I am unable I will have to get approval to review the data model.

Comment: Perhaps I should use a stored procedure that runs after a certain event?

Comment: @AdamSurfari . . . I am a big fan of wrapping all insert/update/delete operations into stored procedures, so I encourage that.  Putting the code in a stored procedure would fix the problem when you do multiple updates.